# How to design a twisted solution to download a file by reading on certain portion?

Tags: python, twisted

How do I download a remote file into several chunks using twisted? Lets say if the file is 100 bytes, I want to spawn 10 connection which will read 10 bytes each but in no particular order and then later on merge them all.

I was able to do this using threads in Python but I don't have any idea how to use twisted's reactor + manager + protocol to achieve the same. Any advice as to how should I design this?

Comment: Using what protocol?  Any transfer of bytes over a network requires a protocol.  Are you downloading the file from an FTP server?  An HTTP server?  A server using some other custom protocol?

Or are you more interested in how one would generally do multiple things in parallel, and not interested in how to use a particular API for a particular protocol?

Comment: using http protocol, I just want to read the accessible file through http.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this really provides the direction the user requires - the question seems to be clear in how to use Twisted to achieve this - the answer implies reasonable knowledge of Twisted.

Comment: We'll I've been reading some twisted materials but still a newbie and my problem is how to design the solution using twisted. Like if I'm to download multiple files, do I need to assign a manager to each file to be downloaded and multiple protocols on each manager for the chunks that needs to be downloaded?